# Can I view the Old Hungarian unicode range in windows 10?

Tags: windows, unicode

I am trying to see some new characters added to the Unicode 8 standard, in Windows 10.  It seems character map can not see any codepoint above $FFFF hex, including the codepoints for the old hungarian script.

I have installed an old hungarian font via Github.  Given that CharMap.exe won't work here, is there any other tool inside Windows that will show me the codepoints?

It is also interesting that the Control panel fonts viewer always uses text in the latin A-Z range (the quick brown fox) on my system, and does not adapt to the actual codepoint content of fonts.

Is there any way in windows 10 to see the contents of a font or to view the accurate Unicode 8 contents of a font above U+FFFF, say U+10C80 ... U+10CFF which is the old-hungarian unicode 8 block.

Comment: There is a test (_Glyph list using **system** Old Hungarian font_)  at http://oldhungarian.eu/index_en.html

Comment: That's a web font.

Comment: You can download and install the font locally that is used on this page [from GitHub](https://github.com/OldHungarian/old-hungarian-font/releases).